# Elements in different divs won't affect each other using :active

Tags: html, css

I need an element to affect another element when clicked even though the other one is in a different div. I'm providing an example to further explain. I'm very grateful for your help or your interest in my problem. Thank you all

http://codepen.io/Kiraken/pen/iedtm

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="first">
        <div id="object"></div>
    </div id="second">
        <div id="second-object">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#container{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    margin: auto;
}
#first{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    margin:auto;
}
#object{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#f05;
}
#second{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    margin:auto;
}
#second-object{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    margin:20px auto;
    background:#333;
}
#second-object:active #object{
     background:#000;   
}
}
```

Comment: Live demos are useful, but questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away. Include your code in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: `div` doesn't have an `:active` state anyways. Also `</div id="second">` isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

### Simply put...you cant (using vanilla CSS)

(sorry)

CSS cannot traverse the DOM 'backwards', i.e. by going up parent levels. Conjoining selectors are only capable of identifying direct descendants, or subsequent siblings as they follow in the DOM (your HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JS to do something like this.

eg. If you were to use jQuery:

```
$('.object-1').click(function(){
  $('.object-2').css('background-color', '#ff0000');
  //or $('.object-2').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: But what if i want to change a background-image?

Comment: In that case you would use ('background-image', 'url(image.png)') but it would be a better practice to add a class and use a background image for that class in the css instead.

Comment: You're a life savior! Thank you